# AJAX return variable from cfc

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to perform an SQL COUNT on my database using AJAX thru a cfc file, however, I have no clue how to get the return variable. The cfc file is as follows

```
<cffunction name="getSpeakerCount" access="remote" returntype="query">
    <cfargument name="AID" required="true" type="string">
        <cfquery name="getSpeaker" datasource="SpeakerCard">
            SELECT COUNT(AID)
            FROM tbl_SpeakerCard_Log
            WHERE AID = '#AID#'
        </cfquery>
    <cfreturn getSpeakerCount>
</cffunction>
```

My ajax is along the lines of this... I'm not sure how to properly call/use it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < X; i++)
{
    $.ajax('actions/AgendaList.cfc?wsdl', {method : 'getSpeakerCount', AID: AgID, dataType: 
"text", type: 'get', success: function(data)
            {
                SCount[i] = data;
            }
            }});
```

This always returns all the elements in SCount[i] as undefined. I'm not sure how to get the count return from the cfc... Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In your query, you should always use cfqueryparam to help prevent SQL Injection attacks.

Also - you are returning `getSpeakerCount` in the function, but your query is called `getSpeaker`

Answer (score 6):

Your function will fail no matter how you call it.  You say you want to return a number but, as pointed out in the comment, you are returning an undefined variable.  This will fix that:

- In your cffunction tag, change the return type from query to numeric.
- In the select clause of your query, use an sql alias to give yourself
  a column name.
- Since your query will only have one field and one row, return that
  value.

So this:

```
<cffunction name="getSpeakerCount" access="remote" returntype="query">
```

becomes this:

```
<cffunction name="getSpeakerCount" access="remote" returntype="numeric">
```

and this:

```
SELECT COUNT(AID)
```

becomes this:

```
SELECT COUNT(AID) records
```

and this:

```
<cfreturn getSpeakerCount>
```

becomes this:

```
<cfreturn getSpeaker.records>
```

The comment about using query paramters is also valid.  Additionally, you should scope that variable.

So this:

```
WHERE AID = '#AID#
```

should be this:

```
WHERE AID = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.aid#">
```

Make sure you can run this using ColdFusion code before trying it with ajax.

Comment: Haha, I took too long and you beat me to it! Good answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful info, I'll test out all the information and try to modify it as needed

Answer (score 3):

(Edit: Took too long typing and Dan beat me to the punch on most of it ;-) Leaving it here as more of an extended comment. See the additional points on testing, return types and formats below).

As mentioned in [your other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279865/calling-a-cfc-function-in-ajax-jquery), it seems like you are trying to tackle too much at once. Approach it one piece at a time. Before you even think about calling a remote function from javascript, verify it works as expected when invoked from a browser.

There are several issues with the function.

- You say you want to return a simple "count", but the function is returning the entire query object. If you wish to return a simple number, return the `count(AID)` value instead.
- In order to use the `count(AID)` outside the query, you need to use a column alias in your SQL ie `SELECT count(AID) AS YourAliasHere ....`.
- The function returns a nonexistent variable, ie `<cfreturn getSpeakerCount>`. To return the count, use the query column instead: `<cfreturn getSpeaker.yourAliasHere>`. Be sure to modify the function [`returnType`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cffunction) as well. It should match the value returned by the function, in this case "numeric".
- By default, functions use `returnformat=wddx`. If you want a different format you need to specify it in the URL, or function signature.
- Lastly, test the function in a browser to ensure that it is returning the expected value - a simple number. Be sure to do a "view source" as well, as wddx will not be fully visible on screen due to the `<` and `>`.

  `http://yourserver.com/path/to/AgendaList.cfc?method=getSpeakerCount&AID={someTe‌​stValueHere}&returnformat={desiredFormatHere}`

As an aside, though it will not cause an error, be sure to localize all function local variables: **that includes query names**. Assuming you are running CF9+, use the Local scope: `<cfquery name="Local.getSpeaker"...>`

Comment: Plus one for mentioning localizing function variables.  My answer did not include that.

Comment: Yea... I only checked the query in my DB to see if it returned the correct value, once it did I just plopped it into a cffunction I was previously using and didn't think to adjust it

Comment: Once you get the cffunction working and plug in the jQuery, it is a good idea to pair your `success()` callback with an `error()` callback. Then you can handle unexpected failures. If you are using jquery 1.8, [success/error are deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), so use:  `done/fail/always()`